# write a query whose column names are based on another table in sql or hive hql

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

I have following table A

```
user_id time   category
Josh    1234   "game"
Tom     5566   "music"
Mary    7788   "reader"
Leon    6666   "game"
Leon    1111   "weather"
...
```

I want to generate a new table B which is based on table A, after I get all the category values.

something like this

```
user_id game music reader weather  ...
josh    1234 0     0       0       ...
tom     0    5566  0       0       ...
Mary    0    0     7788    0       ...
Leon   6666  0     0       1111    ...
```

The new table's column names are from table A.

How can I do that in sql or hive hql (something like `select * from ...` whose output is the new table B.) ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by generate?  Do you mean you want a select statement with that output?

Comment: yes. Something like `select * from ...`

Comment: ok that isn't a "table" that is called a query

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what hive hql is but this is how you do it in SQL

```
SELECT U.user_id, 
       COALESCE(GAME.time,0) as GAME, 
       COALESCE(MUSIC.time,0) as MUSIC, 
       COALESCE(READER.time,0) as READER, 
       COALESCE(WEATHER.time,0) as WEATHER
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id from A) AS U
LEFT JOIN A GAME ON U.user_id = GAME.user_id AND GAME.category = 'game'
LEFT JOIN A MUSIC ON U.user_id = MUSIC.user_id AND MUSIC.category = 'music'
LEFT JOIN A READER ON U.user_id = READER.user_id AND READER.category = 'reader'
LEFT JOIN A WEATHER ON U.user_id = WEATHER.user_id AND WEATHER.category = 'weather'
```

Comment: what if there exists too many category values? If it is, then I need to append 、COALESCE(<category_value>.time,0) as <category_value>、 for many times.

Comment: If you don't know how many categories there are you have to write dynamic SQL that outputs a result which looks like what I have above.  If you know how many then you need **BOTH** the `COALESCE` line and the `LEFT JOIN` line for each category to create that column.

Comment: What is the dynamic SQL?

Comment: @user3378223 you should do a google search to see examples.  dynamic sql is a last resort -- it is when you have a sql code which creates other sql code that then execute.  It is often very slow.